# Slow query in postgresql

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a simple query over one table and the problem is slow performance.
This is the table definition:

```
-- Table: variable_logs

CREATE TABLE variable_logs
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  variable_id integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
  value character varying(255)[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[],
  CONSTRAINT variable_logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE variable_logs
  OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER TABLE variable_logs ALTER COLUMN created_at SET STATISTICS 1000;


-- Index: idx_time_limits_inversed

-- DROP INDEX idx_time_limits_inversed;

CREATE INDEX idx_time_limits_inversed
  ON variable_logs
  USING btree
  (variable_id, created_at DESC);
```

Basically is a table where I save data every X time (example: 10 seconds), and it is growing rapidly. The "value" column only has 1 element in the array for each row.

The Postgresql version is: "PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1, 64-bit"

Now the table has about 653941 rows and the query over the table (without any join) is slow.

```
SELECT   variable_logs.created_at, variable_logs.variable_id, variable_logs.value
FROM variable_logs 
WHERE variable_logs.variable_id = 2
AND (variable_logs.created_at BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
                                  AND '2015-03-09 23:59:00.000000')
ORDER BY created_at asc

Total query runtime: 13979 ms.
184369 rows retrieved.
```

If i execute the same query without order and filter over dates:

```
SELECT variable_logs.created_at, variable_logs.variable_id, variable_logs.value 
FROM variable_logs 
WHERE variable_logs.variable_id = 2

Total query runtime: 14035 ms.
184369 rows retrieved.
```

The query always go slow and I also try to do VACUUM and ANALYZE with the same slow result.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE on, VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS on)
SELECT variable_logs.created_at, variable_logs.variable_id, variable_logs.value 
FROM variable_logs 
WHERE variable_logs.variable_id = 2 
  AND (variable_logs.created_at BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000'  
                                    AND '2015-03-09 23:59:00.000000')  
ORDER BY created_at asc;

"Sort  (cost=32374.66..32835.00 rows=184137 width=53) (actual time=150.983..160.467 rows=184369 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: created_at"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27833kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=8570"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on variable_logs  (cost=5188.10..16271.50 rows=184137 width=53) (actual time=33.239..70.201 rows=184369 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((variable_id = 2) AND (created_at >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-03-09 23:59:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=8570"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_time_limits_inversed  (cost=0.00..5142.06 rows=184137 width=0) (actual time=31.935..31.935 rows=184369 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((variable_id = 2) AND (created_at >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-03-09 23:59:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=709"
"Total runtime: 170.038 ms"
```

I tried to change configuration of postgres.conf following the guide "Things to Try Before You Post" at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions without success ;(

Comment: at first glance, it is mainly the final `order by date_created` (-> sort step) that makes it "slow".

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the question here. Don't link to external resources.

Comment: @wildplasser if I delete the sort order, it is the same ;(.. If i execute the same query without order and filter over dates:

SELECT variable_logs.created_at,variable_logs.variable_id,variable_logs.value FROM variable_logs WHERE variable_logs.variable_id = 2

Total query runtime: 14035 ms. 184369 rows retrieved.

Comment: The `Total runtime: 170.038 ms"` is your slow query?

Comment: @wildplasser 170.038 is the time for "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE on, VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS on)" of the query

Comment: Your index in desc on a column that your query sorts asc on. That seems quirky.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` **does** execute your query (but discards the result)

Comment: @DavidAldridge bad paste - I have a query with "created_at desc" but it is the same... it is slow too ;(

Comment: @wildplasser if EXPLAIN ANALYZE does execute the query... then the problem is when retrieved the data? Then, how I solve this part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving 23% of the rows in the table. I would not expect that using an index would be beneficial, unless it covered all the columns required by the query and provided the required sort order.

Give it a go without the index, and then with an index on (variable_id, created_at, value)

Comment: the same query without the index: Total query runtime: 14575 ms.
184369 rows retrieved.

Comment: with an index on (variable_id, created_at, value) the same query take Total query runtime: 14420 ms. ;(

Comment: You best show the explain analyse results for those also.

Comment: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE on, VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS on) query.... "Seq Scan on plc_engine_variable_logs (cost=0.00..19363.27 rows=183810 width=53) (actual time=0.027..147.689 rows=184369 loops=1)" " Filter: ((created_at >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-03-09 23:59:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (variable_id = 2))" " Buffers: shared hit=224 read=7661" "Total runtime: 155.423 ms @DavidAldridge